# Mirror API - status of whether a user has their account enabled for Mirror API / owns Glass

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is it possible to check via MirrorAPI if a user actually owns Glass or if their account has the Mirror API functionality enabled?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently (As of XE10) no way to do this. It is, however, a requested feature, so you may wish to star https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=107 to register your desire for the feature and to follow progress on it.

The suggestion there, and in other related SO questions, is to do a double-opt-in with the welcome card. This continues with the best practice of creating a welcome card, and also gives it a use to verify that the person can see it.

Answer (score -1):

I think I also read in the mirror api docs, that a user cannot enable the mirror api if they are not a glass explorer: (right under step 2 on https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/php):

> During this stage of the Mirror API Developer Preview, the API is only available to developers who have Glass as part of the Explorer Program.
>
> If you are not an Explorer with Glass, the toggle is not displayed and you cannot enable the Mirror API.

Comment: Actually, any account can oauth through the MirrorAPI even if they don't have Glass. They just cannot enable it in the console.